# How does printf know the length of the format argument?

Tags: c++, c, assembly, printf

```
int printf (const char* format, ... );
```

This is the signature of printf.
What I don't understand is, how does printf know the length of the first argument (the `const char* format`).

It knows the start (because it's a pointer, I get that), but pointers don't have an end or something. Usually when you want to print something you must give a length (For example, Linux's `sys_write`) so how does printf know?

Edit:

I've been looking through the code I wrote in ASM a little more and I think it just looks for a `\0` char. Is that correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is a null-terminated string (like all strings in C), so the first ASCII NUL (`'\0'` or plain `0`) byte indicates the end of the string.

If you have a string `"meow"` in C it actually uses 5 bytes of memory which look like this in memory. The `\0` is obviously a single byte with the value 0.

```
meow\0
```

In case you wonder how an actual `'0'` digit would be represented: The numbers 0..9 have the ASCII values 48..57, so `"me0w"` would have `48` byte at its third position.

Comment: why do we see '\0' instead of '0', there is no character as '\0'. how could it be 1byte?

Comment: @cf16 Characters are just bytes interpreted differently. `48` is interpreted as zero, and 0 is interpreted as NULL.

Comment: Just tried to call `printf` without a `\0` at the end. Computer didn't explode :(. But thanks for assuring me that's the answer.

Comment: ofcourse I know it, by why we see \0, if I define char c='K' there is no \

Comment: The `\0` is added automatically since *all* strings in C have one at the end. And it would be pretty stupid to force the programmer to put it there manually. If you have a single `char` the compiler and functions accepting it *know* that it's just one char so it would be a waste of space to include NUL byte right after it.

Comment: @cf16 Oh, it's just a representation so you the programmer/tester will know it's a NULL and not a zero. (I hope I got your question correct this time). EDIT: Also, if it's just a character than there's no need for a `\0`. It's only handy in strings to know their end.

Comment: just a representation? but if you compare characters of cstring in a loop you have to compare if =="\0" so it's not just representation, isn't it?

Comment: No, you compare `== '\0'` or `== 0` - see the single quotes instead of the double quotes? they tell the compiler it's just a single character. And since `'\0' == 0` you can just write `0` in this case. But once again, `\0` inside a character or string literal tells the compiler to put a null byte at this position. Just like `\n` tells it to put a `13` byte there (which is the ascii code for the linebreak)

Comment: @cf16 That's true, I wasn't specific enough. It's not for representation, but a way to distinct.

Comment: '\0'=='0' ? how could it be? I thought I have just tested recently that if you compare =='0' then it is not right. I'll try it again

Comment: @cf16: No, `'\0' != '0'` -- but `'\0' == 0`.

Comment: @cf16 Never tried it but it makes sense. It'll cast `\0` to it's numeric value which is just 0, and vice-versa. Just my opinion tho, I didn't test it.

Comment: ah, Ok, I see, have to rethink your comment again

Comment: '\0' is the octal escape with one digit. There is no difference between decimal zero and octal zero. You can use '\x0', too.

Comment: '\0' is the character representation of 0, this cannot be just '0' because this is representation of 48, right?

Comment: Please, stop calling the terminating zero character `NULL`. It is not `NULL`. It is sometimes called "NUL character", "zero character", but not `NULL`. `NULL` is a standard macro that serves a completely different and completely unrelated purpose.

Comment: exactly, this gave me a lot of confusion

Comment: but why I can do int ic=65;
    char iToc=ic;
    cout<<"\nic:"<<ic<<"\tiToc:"<<iToc<<endl;  to print A and it is not possible to print characters with codes less than 33?

Comment: how to print '\0' in the similar way (given its 0 decimal rep)?

Comment: @cf16: It is possible to print characters with any code. But many codes do not produce any visible response on the screen. The corresponding "characters" are invisible, they don't have any visible "picture" associated with them. But if you redirect the output to file, you will see that everything got printed correctly.

Comment: for instance int ic=0; char iToc=ic; cout<<"\nic:"<<ic<<"\tiToc:"<<iToc<<endl; will print ic:0     iToc:\0 ?

Comment: @cf16 I don't think it will print `\0`. There's no default output representation for that character like you have for others. You'll just see the integer in the code you wrote. (Didn't test it, pardon me if I'm mistaken)

Comment: I just wonder, finally what it is that char. it is always some stream of bits, and how could it be that machine print some of them and others doesn't. where it is determined?

Comment: Guys, you might want to continue this discussion in [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 1):

When a string is properly declared there is always a NULL (\0) value at the end of it, that marker is used to mark the end of the string for all these printing functions. If it is omitted (difficult to do in most cases) the printing function will just keep printing memory until it runs into a 0 value in memory.

"Anything" is a char array that ends with i n g \0

Edit:
'\0' == 0  and '0' != 0

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't know. Try `printf("Hello \0 World\n");`. `printf` doesn't know that that string contains 15 characters.